# When does the following frobenius norm equality hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-norms

When we consider the square matrix ${\bf A}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$, then following ineqaulity always holds:
$$
\left\|{\bf A^{\sf H}}{\bf A}\right\|_F = \left\|{\bf A}{\bf A^{\sf H}}\right\|_F\le\left\|{\bf A}\right\|_F^2
$$
I'm curious about when the eqaulity holds. I guess only the matrix ${\bf A}$ is zero matrix, i.e., ${\bf A}={\bf 0}$.

Is it true? or not.

Comment: The equality holds for every $A, $ $A=I$ in particular.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc $\sqrt{(1+1+\cdots+1)}\ne(1+1+\cdots+1)$.

Comment: What is the norm with index $F$ ? I thought it was an operator norm.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Sorry for confusing. I meant the frobenius norm.

Comment: Ok. I call it the Hilbert-Schmidt norm. Take the diagonal matrix with one nonzero entry on the diagonal. The equality should hołd.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Thanks. Is there general condition for this eqaulity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the singular value decomposition we have
$$Ax=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k \langle x, u_k\rangle v_k,$$ where $\{u_k\}_{k=1}^n$ and
$\{u_k\}_{k=1}^n$ are orthonormal bases and $\lambda_k$ form a nonincreasing collection of nonnegative numbers.
Then
$$A^HAx=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k^2 \langle x, u_k\rangle u_k\quad{\rm and}\quad  
\|A^HA\|_F=\left (\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k^4\right )^{1/2}$$
Furthermore $Au_i=\lambda_iv_i$ and
$$\|A\|_F^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^n|\langle Au_i,u_j\rangle |^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\lambda_i^2|\langle v_i,u_j\rangle |^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2\sum_{j=1}^n|\langle v_i,u_j\rangle |^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2$$
Therefore equality holds if and only if
$$\left (\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2\right )^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^4$$
Thus $\lambda_2=\ldots =\lambda_n=0.$

Summarizing the equality holds if and only if the rank of the matrix $A$ is less than or equal to $1.$

Comment: Kindly correct the typo in the last line in your answer: I think you meant ".... if and only if the rank of the matrix $A$ is less than or equal to 1"

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo

Comment: Thanks for kind explanation!:)